# How can I have multiple items or element in a sql cell?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

I want to create a database that has the table for sales and services for a certain company. What I want to know (since I don't know much of SQL) if there a way to store like an object that represents a list or array in a single cell. Why? Because I want a cell in the Sales table to point to all the services that generated that particular sale. For example:

A sale of in 09/09/11 that was generated by service_1, service_2, ... , service_n . Where service_# is a certain service that this particular company offers. Again I apologize for my stupidity but I'm now in the process of learning SQL.

I'm planning to create the database on SQL server.

Comment: To be honest.. I could post a way to store multiple values in one cell, but I'd rather not.. because it's not a good approach, and I'd like to pay it forward and help newbies get on the right track without having to make those mistakes, because this is one thing where you can learn from it without experiencing it. Here's one place , of many, many, that you should try to read to the end about: http://www.agiledata.org/essays/dataModeling101.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bad approach.
Database must be well normalized. You are talking to make a design that is not in [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

That you are loking for is a N:M relation ship, you should create a new table called sale_services:

```
sales (saleId, ...)
services (servideId, name, price, ...)
sale_services( saleId, serviceId)
```

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, as soon as you want to add multiple things in one cell, change your database design. Split the tables. Use one table called Sales, another called Services and then a last one that joins the two together which has the ids of the sales and services you want to "join".

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, just wanting to store an array is a sign that you are designing incorrectly. If you want an array of data, what you really need is a related table to store that information in individual records.

What I want to talk about is what happens when you decide to store an array in a field, separated by a comma for instance.

Suppose you store the available colors of a product in a field called colors.

Now you have

```
Product Colors 
item1   red, blue, yellow 
item2   blue, purple, red
```

and so forth for a million records

Now how do you find all the products that come in red? Array fields are difficult to properly query and the performance when you do so is generally abysmal. Adding a new color is also a pain point especially if you want it to be in a certain order.

Before you go any farther in designing a database you need to read about normalization and database design. One of the very first rules of database design is **NEVER** store more than one piece of information in a field in a record. This is a complex subject and making the wrong choice early on can kill your system. Database are not simple or easy to refactor so you need to know what you are doing at the time you create the design.

Comment: Thank you. I've will study more about normalization and see how can I come up with a better solution. My issue was that I couldnt generate another table for the relation in between Sales and Services because a single sale can be generated by any combination of services. I can't have another table with all the variants of the different services, that is too big. So, maybe I need to re-design my DB.

Comment: Then you probaly need a sales table and servie table and a linking table called SalesService. And remeber SQL Server can easily handle trillions of records, I seriously doubt it will be too big as long asyou you index it properly.

Comment: Guy thanks for all the comments. I'll do as you say. We live to learn :)

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good comments here.

You might want to take a step back and look at the bigger picture of your database.   The comments here are from practical experience, not just text books.   Try to see what other uses will happen with your data.   In your example, if you stored the service list in a single cell, like you mentioned, how would you determine which service was performed the most?   How about what services are never used?  If your solution requires reading every "row" and doing something, than most likely there is a better approach.

If you put together a suggested design, many people here will help you tweak it and fine-tune it to make it better..

Good luck...

Comment: Sorry again. How can I normalize the tables if I don't know at prior to how many services will a sale make reference to. Eg: Sale1 can refer to ServiceId_1, ServiceId2, ServiceId_6,...    or  can be ServiceId_8, ServiceId_10,...     unless I have to completely redesign the database

Comment: Any time you have mulitple values in a single field, you should immediately think of creating a table to hold each individual value.  The table should contain an ID that links back to the first table and then a field to hold each element.   This way, each service would be its own row in the table, so you can handle any number of services simply by adding new rows to the joining table.  If you look at DaniHp's answer, the Sale_service table is an example of how to split out the multiple services.